# Unity: Onmouseup while dragging UI element over it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my 2D project I can't seem to get OnMouseUp working while dragging a UI object over it. I want to be able to detect that I dropped the UI object on a non-UI gameobject so I can activate the script that lets the position of the UI object be the same position as the non-UI object each Update.

Currenty I use the IOnDragHandler and IEndDragHandler on the UI object for the dragging process. When I want to drop the UI object on another UI object then IDropHandler helps me, but when I want to drop it on a non-UI GameObject, I want to be able to use the OnMouseUp event, but it doesn't fire.

Whenever I start dragging the object I use a CanvasGroup on the UI object and I make sure that it doesn't get hit by any raycasts.

I also tried making the collider of the non-UI object a trigger but it has no effect. Also, OnMouseOver and OnMouseExit do work when I am dragging the UI element over the non-UI element.

Thanks very much for looking into this. Here comes the code:

So on the UI object (A card) I use this:

```
   public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (CanDrag)
        {
            if (!isDragging)
            {
                isDragging = true;
                if (Slot != null)
                {
                    Slot.GetComponent<FamilyTreePlacementScript>().CurrentFamilyCard = null;
                }

                if (card is FamilyCard || card is EquipmentCard) UIManagerScript.Instance.ToggleFamilyTree(null, true);
                GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
                CardManagerScript.CardBeingDragged = gameObject;
                DataKeeperScript.Instance.MayDragCamera = false;
                CardManagerScript.Instance.DeletePreview();
                transform.SetParent(canvas);
            }

            transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
        }
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (CanDrag)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
            CardManagerScript.CardBeingDragged = null;
            DataKeeperScript.Instance.MayDragCamera = true;

            if (Slot == null)
            {
                transform.SetParent(defaultParent);
            }
            else
            {
                Slot.GetComponent<FamilyTreePlacementScript>().CurrentFamilyCard = card as FamilyCard;
                transform.SetParent(Slot);
                transform.position = Slot.position;
            }
        }        
    }
```

And on the non-UI object that I want to "drop" the card on, I use:

```
private void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (CardManagerScript.CardBeingDragged)
    {
        Card card = CardManagerScript.CardBeingDragged.GetComponent<CardObjectScript>().card;

        if (card is TakeOverCard)
        {
            //Check if the card can actually be played

            if (Business.Allegiance != CardManagerScript.Instance.PlayerFamily)
            {
                CurrentTakeOverCard = card;
                CardManagerScript.CardBeingDragged.GetComponent<CardObjectScript>().SetWorldObject(transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you place a breakpoint or `Debug.Log`on the very top of the `MouseUp()`, does it brake/show anything when you release it on top of your GameObject?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response --> Gamescom. A debug.log only shows when I hover the mouse over the non-UI object without dragging the card. As soon as the UI card object is in between the mouse and the non-UI object the debug.log doesn't show.

Comment: Well that is because you need to disable the `RaycastTarget` Boolean on your UI element that you are dragging, since its probably hitting that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'Queries Hit Triggers' (Project Settings > Physics). It should be set to 'true'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is already the case. Both for physics2d & 3d. It is a 2D project btw.

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks, Ok. What type of collider you used for the "non-UI" object? Is that collider set up properly? What rotation value is used for the non-UI object? Is it (0,0,0) or something else?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response --> Gamescom. I just use a box collider 2D, tried with and without "is trigger" enabled. The collider is also big enough.

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks, can you make some Inspector window screenshots with "non-UI" and "UI" objects selected? It would be nice if you can publish a test project showing the problem.